# Sourcery G++ (cross-compiler for ARM) installation failure

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, codesourcery

I was trying to install Sourcery G++ cross-compiler for ARM on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS from the following link ->http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/release644
I did not use the graphical interface since I got java.awt error. While using the console mode of installation, I provided all the details asked by the program.(changed the default location of installation)

Some time into the installation, I got this error:

### Unable to create file links

An error occurred while running an internal program.
Please remove the toolchain from "/home//cross_compiler".
EXITCODE=-1

I'm not sure what the reason is. I redid this process as a root user and I still got the same error.I am trying to install this on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Post a question on the [CodeBench Support Portal](https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/) and ask there. Lite edition doesn't get any paid-for support, of course, but if the installer isn't working they'd like to know about it and will probably help you out.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose it is important to check your system requirements.

There is the possibility you are running a 64bit build of Ubuntu.

Sourcery G++ requires 32bit host libraries. Ensure those are installed.

In my mind, it may be easier to run a 32bit installation in a VM.

If that is not possible, there are installation logs in the 'uninstall' directory of your installation attempt directory. That may help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. The 64bit Ubuntu machine doesn't have 32 bit host libraries as of now. Maybe that's a reason. I did check out the logs inside the Uninstall directory, but all the processes went through successfully without a single error.

Comment: Installing 32bit Host libraries solved the problem. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs for those that want to know what the command is to make codesourcery and other 32 bit tools work on ubuntu 64 bit

Answer (score 3):

You must have the 32-bit compatibility libraries installed to install Sourcery CodeBench.

From the FAQ: "What do I need to do to install and run Sourcery CodeBench on an x86 64-bit Linux host system?"
https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/kbentry62

Full FAQ here:
https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/target_arch?@action=faq&target_arch=arm

The ARM Lite edition tools have their own mailing list where you can ask such questions.
Go to sourcerytools.com and use the "arm-gnu" mailing list for ARM Lite edition questions.

Cheers!